# How to get rid of the horizontal scroller bar from website

Tags: html, css

sorry this question was asked previously, it seems like I wasn't clear enough, 
I do know the problem of this scrollerbar is due to css, some tutorial said that width: 100% is the cause of the problem but by eliminating the width:100% still I ended up with the same problem. 
I'll let examine my web app that I'm working on in a hope of some answer

http://www.kefet.com/content/videoview.html?pl=PLvnIwAWCv4j3xZdRkB2MwY8-l7_jz7ngy&v=alJoYgvcY9E&cat=sls_mo&plid=36

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it was the margin-left:230 way over the container css class that I have created.

how to find problem like this: use the firebug to detect which css is causing the problem and edited.

Thank you